# How does dart implement library privacy under the hood?

Tags: dart, package, private

When a library name is prefixed with a '_' it becomes private to its library. How does the dart vm actually implement this privacy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, the VM suffixes the variable name with a string that is unique to the library, so `_foo` might become `_foo@1238fa12`. The `@` ensures that it can't collide with a user variable because `@` isn't valid in a normal identifier. After appending the string, the VM can treat the variable as a completely normal variable, and because there is no other library that can possibly have a reference to the variable, it is effectively library private (although there are probably a few corner cases where it needs to be more clever about private names).

That's not the only possible implementation strategy, but private variables were designed from the beginning to make this strategy possible.

Comment: when you write _foo@1238fa12, is "1238fa12" the hashcode that would get returned from the hashCode getter on the mirror of _foo (returned from reflect(_foo) if _foo is an instance or class). In other words, Could I deduce this generated name in my dart code and somehow call that private function?

Comment: I actually don't know where the random-looking string comes from. You can call private functions directly using mirrors, so you don't need to know the mangled name. You can never call it directly from Dart code because `_foo@1238fa12` is not a valid identifier, even if you know it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know are the names prefixed with a random string which is unique per library.